# Second Isomorphism Theorem For Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

I am trying to understand this proof

[image]

In the line before last why does it say that the image of $f$ is $(S+T)/T$? Isn't the image of $f$ is $M/T$?

Comment: By definition we have $x\in S$ and $f(x)=x+T$. So what is the image? Note that $S\subset M$, but not necessarily $S=M$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, but then why is the image is not $S/T$ instead of $(S+T)/T$?

Comment: This is because $S$ doesn't necessarily contain $T$, so $S/T$ is meaningless. However, modulo $T$,  the submodule $S+T$ (which contains $T$)defines exactly the same classes as $S$. Actually, $S+T$ is the *smallest* submodule of $M$ which contains both $S$ and $T$.

Comment: $T$ need not be a submodule of $S$, so what do you mean by $S/T$?

Comment: The *range* of $f$ is $M/T$.  The *image* of $S$ under $f$ is by definition $f(S)$, and is 
$$f(S)=\{x+T:x\in S\}=(S+T)/T.$$